# Swipe.js getPos() and getNumSlides() help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, carousel

I am currently using Swipe.js (https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/blob/master/README.md) for a carousel I am using for a website. I am a little new to this and could use some help. My code is below and saved an abbreviated sample at http://jsfiddle.net/eg5d2/1/ to make life a little easier. Thanks!

Swipe exposes a few functions that can be useful for script control of your slider.

prev() slide to prev

next() slide to next

getPos() returns current slide index position

getNumSlides() returns the total amount of slides

slide(index, duration) slide to set index position (duration: speed of transition in milliseconds)

```
                            <div id='mySwipe4' class='swipe'>
                            <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="activation-1.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="activation-1.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="activation-1.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="activation-1.jpg" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div id="slide-indicators">INSERT SLIDE INIDCATOR HERE / TOTAL NUMBER OF SLIDES</div>
<script>
    window.mySwipe4 = new Swipe(document.getElementById('mySwipe4'), {
  continuous: true,
  disableScroll: false,
  stopPropagation: false

});
</script>
```

Comment: Anyone able to help me out with this one?

Comment: I'm working through this same challenge right now myself. I'm close to figuring it out. I'll post back here as soon as I figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I removed the `disableScroll` and `stopPropagation` values, as those are false by default.

```
<div id='mySwipe4' class='swipe'>
    <div class='swipe-wrap'>
        <div>
            <img src="activation-1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="activation-1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="activation-1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="activation-1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slide-indicators">1 / 1</div>

<script src="swipe.js"></script>
<script>
    // Variables
    var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe4');
    var currentSlide = getPos() + 1; // because slide count starts at 0
    var totalSlides = getNumSlides();

    // Functions
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
      continuous: true,
      callback: function(index, element) {
        document.getElementById('slide-indicators').innerHTML = currentSlides + ' / ' + totalSlides;
      }
    });
    document.getElementById('slide-indicators').innerHTML = currentSlides + ' / ' + totalSlides;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing those typos!